# how to Read the mail using python and flask

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to write a restapi to Read the mail and Download the attachments along with sender mail, Subject of email, email body in text file. But i am getting some errors.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and the error messages to your question.

Comment: I am unable to decode body of mails.unable to download attatchments.